# Paypal IPN does not create Commerce Order

Tags: commerce, payment-gateways

I use drupal commerce and paypal wps for payment. If you pay and folllow the links back to my site, the order is created. But if you just pay and leave the site, no order is created although an IPN is showing up in the log ([payment_status] => Completed).

I'm working with a live version, no localhost.
Can someone help me, please?